# Play Framework - Qual versão é a mais recomendada para usar?

Tags: java, play-framework

Comecei a tentar aprender play framework e vi que até a versão 2.2.x tudo era feito à partir do concole digitando o comando "play new, play run, etc" e, só que para executar essa versão teria que ser necessário desatualizar o java que atualmente é o Java 8 para o Java 7 ou 6, mas depois dessa versão vi que o uso agora é do activator no terminal, alguém saberia me dizer qual o mais recomendável?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A versão **2.4.3**, é a última versão e tende a ser a mais estável, sendo a última ela resolve alguns bugs das versões anteriores. Como você viu agora pode utilizar o activator em linha de comando, funciona normalmente e totalmente compatível com a versão 8 do Java, uma forma de desenvolver sistemas reativos de forma mais simples  também.

E já que você está aprendendo sobre o Play Framework, uma boa forma de aprender é utilizando o comando `activator ui`. Com esse comando você tem uma interface completa pra te ensinar sobre o Play.

Comment: Saquei, no começo tive um pouco de dificuldade para instalar o activator, mas deu tudo certo. Obrigado pelo esclarecimento e pela dica!